# Removing divs using jQuery after index N

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Markup:

```
<div id="status">
    <div style="display: block;">Status OK - 16:57:09.</div>
    <div style="display: block;">Status OK - 16:57:09.</div>
    <div style="display: block;">Status OK - 16:57:05.</div>
    <div style="display: block;">Status OK - 16:57:05.</div>
    <div style="display: block;">Status OK - 16:57:03.</div>
    <div>No status yet.</div>
</div>
```

Using AJAX, I'm adding a new Div to the status div. I only want five divs to be inside at all time. Meaning after the sixth ajax class, the last div should be removed.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Update() {
        PurgeOldStatuses();
        $("#status").children().first().hide().fadeIn();
    }

    function PurgeOldStatuses() {
        // From the status div, find all divs with index after 5, and remove them.
        $("#status").$("div:gt(5)").remove();
    }
</script>
```

I wrote in a comment to illustrate what **I think** is going on, perhaps I'm wrong.

Currently not elements are removed. Any suggestions why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to get better performance, avoid proprietary selectors like `:gt()`, and only use valid CSS selectors.

This should be very quick:

```
$("#status").find("div").slice(5).remove();
```

or this:

```
$("#status div").slice(5).remove();
```

---

*From the docs for the [`gt-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/):*

> Because `:gt()` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using `:gt()` cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()` method. *For better performance in modern browsers, use `$("your-pure-css-selector").slice(index)` instead.*

Note that the docs recommend using the [`slice()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method, which grabs all elements in the set starting at the zero-based index you provide.

Comment: Aha, let me test that bit out.

Answer (score 3):

> $("#status").find("div:gt(4)").remove();

Start with the element `#status`, then `find` looks for all descendants (of `#status`) matching the selector `div:gt(4)`. Then `remove` gets rid of them.

The reason it's 4 (not 5), is that javascript is zero-based - the first element is 0. Thanks to Mark for pointing this out.

The genius of jQuery is chaining - each function in the chain returns the set of elements it was passed, so you can 'drill down'

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on why this works? I'll mark it as accepted in the meantime after the timer runs out. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can't stack selectors like this " $("#status").$("div:gt(5)")"

Comment: This leaves 6 not 5 due to the 0 base.

Comment: Thanks Mark, missed that one.

Answer (score 2):

This line is wrong:

```
 $("#status").$("div:gt(5)").remove();
```

should be:

```
 $("#status").find("div:gt(4)").remove();
```

EDIT: `$` is not a property or method of the jQuery object, but find is a method on the object returned by the function $().

Comment: You cannot use the $ selector inside a selection. It works like that :)

Comment: @Sergio Tapia: `$("#status")` returns a jquery object, when you follow that with a `$("div:gt(5)")`, you're calling a jquery object within a jquery object as a function.

Comment: $ is not a selector it is the same as `jQuery("#status").jQuery("..` NOTE you could also use: $("#status").children("div:gt(4)").remove();` OR `$("#status>div:gt(4)").remove();` use 4 because of the 0 base.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#status > div:gt(5)").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

To leave 5 child div's with the shortest selector:

```
$("#status>div:gt(4)").remove();
```